# apache - virtual host logging

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have a virtualhost setup with usecanonicalname off.

I have ServerName domain.com set and ServerAlias *.domain.com in the virtualhost.

Using apache2's %v LogFormat string will only capture domain.com, and I'm trying to get it to capture foo.domain.com so I can split logs accordingly.

LogFormat I'm currently using is

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **%{Host}i** on your log format should give you the content of the "Host" header... which appears to be what you want.

Quote from the documentation:

> %{Foobar}i - The contents of Foobar: header line(s) in the request sent
>   to the server. Changes made by other modules (e.g. mod_headers) affect
>   this. If you're interested in what the request header was prior to
>   when most modules would have modified it, use mod_setenvif to copy the
>   header into an internal environment variable and log that value with
>   the %{VARNAME}e described above.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stick a separate CustomLog and ErrorLog directive into each virtual host definition?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@place
DocumentRoot /var/www/hosted/place/root
ServerName www.place
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
CustomLog /var/www/hosted/place/logs/access_log combined
ErrorLog /var/www/hosted/place/logs/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Because I don't want to set a new virtualhost for every subdomain we have, there's no need for it, they all share the same directives. I want to accept requests for *.foo.com in one place, but have logs that say a.foo.com, b.foo.com, c.foo.com etc.